Is there a Linux utility to allow users to request new passwords?
For various reasons mostly for not needing to remember the password I forget the account passwords and I need to perform a command that requires a password, such as using sudo when I haven't used it for a long time.
It is usually due to using SSH keys to log in most of the time and needing a command which needs the password such as changing the shell, running sudo or some other command that prompts for the existing password.
As far as security is concerned being able to log into the shell implies the user is authorized to execute the command.
In this case I want the command to generate a new password and output it on the screen, using some pwgen like utility.

Why not just give these users NOPASSWD on sudo?

@muru It is not just sudo. The sudo user is common one I forget, but it should be for any user who has forgotten the password, but is able to log into their account because they have the right credentials. I'm thinking of using some setuid script to accomplish this but I am sure others have gotten there before me, and have more knowledge of the gotchas to be avoided.

But if you do give NOPASSWD sudo access, you can also give access to a script to change their password (or if they have unlimited sudo access anyway, then just NOPASSWD will allow them to change passwords as needed). Scripts can't be setuid on Linux, so which OS are you using?

@muru I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of sudo, I just use the one created by the installer. However from the bit I know I have to give NOPASSWD access to the specific script for changing the password and other such scripts.
Is there a way of giving a particular group of scripts NOPASSWD access, eg by placing them in a particular directory?

Sure, you can specify a directory instead of a command, and: "When you specify a directory in a Cmnd_List, the user will be able to run any file within that directory (but not in any sub-directories therein)" (from man 5 sudoers)

Now you understand why many devices such as iOS and macOS devices ask for your pin/password at least once a week even if you usually use Face ID/Touch ID: one important reason is to make sure you still remember your password in case you need it (such as after a restart).

Consider using a pasword manager, so you don't need to remember your passwords in the first place.

You could create a program such as this:
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]
then
  exec /bin/passwd $SUDO_USER
else
  echo Must be run with sudo
fi

Let's call this /usr/local/bin/reset-password (for example).
Now you can have a sudo rule:
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/reset-password

Then a user can run sudo /usr/local/bin/reset-password and they will be allowed to change their password without needing to enter it first.
This should be safe because sudo itself sets the SUDO_USER variable, and if you don't run this under sudo then you don't have permissions to change anyone except your own password.
If the user already has a rule such as %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL then this might force a password to be required, in which case that rule can be rewritten as %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL,!/usr/local/bin/reset-password so it doesn't match and the passwordless entry will then work.
You could easily add in a "password generator" component to this script and pass it to the passwd command.

note that /usr/local/bin/reset-password  (or whatever name you're using) MUST NOT be writeable by anyone you do not want to have root access to the system, as it would trivial for them to simply change the script to a root shell.

Any reason not to call sudo within the script? I guess one reason is because doing so is frowned upon by some. I definitely don't want a third party installer script to invoke sudo, but i don't mind using it in my own scripts.

@JeremyImpson If the idea is to use NOPASSWD, then better that be with reset-password rather than passwd, since the latter would let them change the password of anyone. Though, I suppose one could switch the echo Must be run with sudo for sudo "$0" or similar.
